# Unbiasedness of an estimator

Tags: estimators

I want to show that the following estimator is an unbiased estimator of E(X):

$\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N/2}(X_i + \mu) + \frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=N/2+1}^{N}(X_i - \mu)$

In other words, I want to show that the expected value of the expression above is exactly equal to $\mu$ but I am still getting $2\mu$ even though the correct answer should be that it is indeed an unbiassed estimator...Thanks

edit: The solution is indeed $2\mu$ which makes it a biased estimator. I got in touch with the author of the problem set and it has been fixed. Thank you for help.

Comment: Hint: Rewrite $$\frac{2}{N}\sum(X_i\pm\mu)=\frac{2}{N}\left(\sum X_i\right)\pm\frac{2}{N}\left(\mu\frac{N}{2}\right).$$ Don't misread this as implying there's any connection whatsoever between $\mu$ and the $X_i;$ in particular, $\mu$ needn't equal the expectation.

Comment: I did it and I am still getting $2\mu$. The part on the right of the plus sign is just zero and the $2\mu$ is the left side...

Comment: Show your work in the question

Comment: This is how I got my answer:
$\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(Xi)+\frac{2}{N}\frac{N}{2}\mu+\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=n/2+1}^{n}(Xi)-\frac{2}{N}\frac{N}{2}\mu$
$=\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(Xi)+\mu+\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=n/2+1}^{n}(Xi)-\mu$

$=\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(Xi)+\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=n/2+1}^{n}(Xi)$

$=E[\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(Xi)+\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=n/2+1}^{n}(Xi)]=\frac{2}{N}E[\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(Xi)]+\frac{2}{N}E[\sum_{i=n/2+1}^{n}(Xi)]=\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}E[Xi]+\frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=n/2+1}^{n}E[Xi]$

$=\frac{2}{N}\frac{N}{2}\mu+\frac{2}{N}\frac{N}{2}\mu=2\mu$

Comment: Good work (+1): you have proven the claim incorrect; and your method suggests what the intended formula might have been: what happens when the values of $2/N$ are replaced by $1/N$?  (Another possibility is that $\mu$ was intended to be the common expectation of the $X_i$ but that the "$+$" in the first sum should have been "$-.$")

Comment: If you finally arrive at the answer, you can answer this question yourself with all the steps and then accept your own answer, so this thread will be more useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is indeed $2\mu$ which makes it a biased estimator. I got in touch with the author of the problem set and it has been fixed. Thank you for help.